# Keep serverside validation on second page load?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, model-view-controller

new to programming had a issue. While completing my form, in the section Preferred way of communication, when checkbox "Mobile telephone" is selected, "Confirm mobile number" textbox also shows because my JavaScript code to show the confirm textbox dynamically. If I enter different value from “Mobile telephone” textbox in the "Confirm mobile number" textbox and submit the form, thenvalidation gets fired under the "Confirm mobile number" textbox mentioning "Please ensure confirm mobile number matches".

However the textbox "Confirm mobile number" textbox disappears from the screen when the form is by a user. Because of server side validation, when the form is loaded the second time "Confirm mobile number" textbox is hidden again and if I select radio "Mobile telephone", "Confirm mobile number" text box shows again, but this with the validation message under it.

Just confused why textbox don't remember my checked value to show the validated text box, after the form is submitted, I assume this is because of my JavaScript. PLEASE HELP AND ADVISE

Below is my model with server side validation code:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select preferred way of communication option.")]
public Commmunication? CCommmunication
{ get; set; }

public enum Commmunication
{

[Display(Name = "Mobile telephone", Order = 0)]
TelephoneNo
}


public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{
if (this.CCommmunication == Commmunication.TelephoneNo && string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.MobileTelephoneNo))
{
yield return new ValidationResult("Please enter telephone number", new[] { "MobileTelephoneNo" }); //returns message
}
// Confirm ConfirmMobileTelephoneNo matches.
if (this.CCommmunication == Commmunication.TelephoneNo && ConfirmMobileTelephoneNo != MobileTelephoneNo)
{
yield return new ValidationResult("Please ensure confirm mobile number matches", new[] { "ConfirmMobileTelephoneNo" }); //returns message
}
```

2: My view HTML code

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<!-- <i class="fa fa-phone-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>-->
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.MobileTelephoneNo, "Type in your mobile telephone no:", new { @style = "", @class = "", id = "" })
<span class="mobiletelredstar" style="display:none">*</span>
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MobileTelephoneNo, new { placeholder = "Enter your mobile no", @style = "", @class = "form-control", id = "MobileTelephoneNo" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MobileTelephoneNo)
</div>

<div id="ConfirmMobTelNo" class="confirmmobtelno col-md-6" style="display:none">
<!--  <i class="fa fa-phone-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>-->
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfirmMobileTelephoneNo, "Confirm your mobile telephone no:", new { @style = "", @class = "", id = "" })
<span class="mobiletelredstar" style="display:none">*</span>
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ConfirmMobileTelephoneNo, new { placeholder = "Re-enter your mobile no", @style = "", @class = "form-control", id = "ConfirmMobileTelephoneNo" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmMobileTelephoneNo)
</div>
```

3: My JavaScript code:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {

$('.communicationRB input[name=CCommmunication]').click(function () {
if ($(this).val() == "TelephoneNo") {
$('.confirmmobtelno').show(); //show this text box
$('.mobiletelredstar').show();
} else {
$('.confirmmobtelno').hide(); //hide textbox
$('.mobiletelredstar').hide();
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: When the form is posted make sure you send the model to the view when the model is not valid. The view will take the value from your model, render it and it will be sent back to the user. Also you are not doing server side validation properly. You are making it harder. Read a tutorial on form submission and validation in asp mvc.

Comment: I don't think you understood my question, a textbox that's validates hides again after validation.

Comment: I did understand your question. When the user posts the form it hits your controller and if your controller action accepts a model, that model needs to have a boolean value to carry the state of your checkbox. If not valid, the view will use that value and get rendered. I understand your question perfectly clear

Comment: My textbox hides again after validation, when I need it to be displayed again on my checkbox selection

Comment: @CodingYosh I want to reload the page with the related hidden displayed based on the selected radio input

Comment: In your javascript when the user clicks the checkbox, you do some work and show some controls. When the form is shown the 2nd time, there will be no click. You need to do that based on whether the checkbox is selected. That selection needs to be done on the server side before you resend the form to the user. So you need to check if the checkbox is preselected when the document loads.

Comment: @CodingYoshi if you have the chance, can you please modify my JavaScript above so I can paste it on my visual studio, as I am new to programming?

Comment: Here is how to check: `if($("idOfYourCheckbox").is(":checked")) {//do what you need to do}`. I am not home or else I would answer your question.

Comment: @CodingYoshi when you get home please do, I've tried a lot, going to give up on this for now. please answer my question and I appreciate your help sir

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in here. Your server is accepting your validation information, but not being sent back to your client. You need to include that information within your response back to your webpage.

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
    if (this.CCommmunication == Commmunication.TelephoneNo && string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.MobileTelephoneNo))
    {
    yield return new ValidationResult("Please enter telephone number", new[] { "MobileTelephoneNo" }); //returns message
    }
    // Confirm ConfirmMobileTelephoneNo matches.
    if (this.CCommmunication == Commmunication.TelephoneNo && ConfirmMobileTelephoneNo != MobileTelephoneNo)
    {
    yield return new ValidationResult("Please ensure confirm mobile number matches", new[] { "ConfirmMobileTelephoneNo" }); //returns message
    }
```

In my experience, we usually solve this problem using classes called [models](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/overview/understanding-models-views-and-controllers-cs). Your validation information is contained within that object, and it's returned in the same response that you send your webpage. Ex:

```
return("View", model);
```

This process can be complicated initially, it's worth reading up on.